# Experiencing errors by drawing spritesheet with Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm practicing Canvas by building a walking figure, which is made of 30 sprite's on a spritesheet. Check this on the [following site](http://sem.serialshop.nl/jelle/sprite2/index.html).

But as you can seen it doesn't look any fluent. And I got 2 Cannot call method of undefined errors for `clearRect` and `drawImage`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you have an idea where your problems arise? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to adjust the spritesheet sizes, and I looked for typho's, but I really dont know what's causing it

Answer (score 1):

I checked the code on your site, here's the issue: ctx is not populated by the value in your init function() when it's first run.

Your draw() function starts when the image is loaded in the header, which is loaded before the body is loaded.

With regards to the image shifting off to the side for some areas, check the math. It could easily be that your cropping the wrong section

EDIT: Here's what should be in your script, it stays in the Head tag

```
var ctx;
var count = 0;
var x;
var y;

var img = new Image();


function draw()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 171, 192);

    x = (count % 6 ) * (934/6);
    y = Math.floor(count / 6) * 192;
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 934/6, 192, 0, 0, 171, 192);
    if(count == 29)
        count = 0;
    else
        count++;
}

function init()
{
    ctx = document.getElementById('canvas01').getContext("2d");
    img.src="img/sprites.jpg";
    img.onload = draw;
}
```

Comment: So do you mean I have to place the javascript at the end of my body tag?